# php mysql dropdown issue

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, dropdown

I am trying to build a dropdown list from my sql database. 
Managed to get it work somewhat, but the list only shows the last item in the table, and i briefly get this printed on the page as the page reloads:

```
[
 {"id":"1","zavod_ime":"PEIT"},
 {"id":"2","zavod_ime":"PTJM"},
 {"id":"3","zavod_ime":"PM"},
 {"id":"4","zavod_ime":"PN"},
 {"id":"5","zavod_ime":"BS"}
]
```

this is my separate php file which handles connecting and putting things in an array:

```
    $sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, zavod_ime FROM zavod")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $arrVal = array();

    while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {

                    $namez = array(
                        'id'=> $rowList['id'],
                        'zavod_ime'=> $rowList['zavod_ime']
                        );      


                        array_push($arrVal, $namez);    
    }
         echo  json_encode($arrVal);        


    mysqli_close($con);
```

and the list part in the html:

```
                    <select>
                        <?php foreach($namez as $zavod): ?>
                        <option value="<?= $namez['id']; ?>"><?= $namez['zavod_ime']; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
```

ideas?

Comment: You're seeing the JSON object as you have echoed a json encoded array.

Comment: change it to this if you want array : `echo  json_encode($arrVal, true);`

Comment: you should mark off questions with solutions given; you get good rep back also

Answer (score 5):

You need `arrVal` to loop instead of `namez`

```
<select>
    <?php foreach($arrVal as $namez): ?>
    <option value="<?= $namez['id']; ?>"><?= $namez['zavod_ime']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you are using echo in `echo json_encode($arrVal);` that is why your data is displaying. 

If you are using ajax to retrieve data you should use `echo` followed by `die()`

Also you are returning `json_encode` so before you use that value decode the value.

**The following is assuming that you are using** `include` **at the top of where you want your** `select`

```
<?php $arrVal = json_decode($arrVal)?>
<select>
    <?php foreach($arrVal as $namez): ?>
    <option value="<?= $namez['id']; ?>"><?= $namez['zavod_ime']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: now i am seeing this in the list: 
    Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /storage/ssd1/720/2097720/public_html/home.php on line 144

Comment: and also, how would the code without json_encode go?

Comment: insted of `echo  json_encode($arrVal);` do this `$arrVal = json_encode($arrVal)`, this will encode the array, but i think now you are getting the data as array so you are getting the error

Comment: did that and now i get:<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: arrval in <b>/storage/ssd1/720/2097720/public_html/home.php</b> on line <b>146</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/storage/ssd1/720/2097720/public_html/home.php</b> on line <b>146</b><br />

Answer (score 0):

managed to make things work:

```
    $sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, zavod_ime FROM zavod")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $arrVal = array();

    while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {

                    $namez = array(
                        'id'=> $rowList['id'],
                        'zavod_ime'=> $rowList['zavod_ime']
                        );      


                        array_push($arrVal, $namez);    
    }
         echo  json_encode($arrVal);        


    mysqli_close($con);
```

and html:

```
                        <?php foreach($arrVal as $namez): ?>
                        <option value="<?= $namez['id']; ?>"><?= $namez['zavod_ime']; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```